# Emacs stuck on infinite loop when trying to use ghc-mod

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc-mod

I've been trying to learn Haskell the last couple of days so it was finally time to setup my environment. Thus, I installed Haskell Platform and cabal.

My editor is emacs and my OS is Windows.

I downloaded the ghc-mod's master branch from github and using cabal I installed the dependencies and then built the project. Everything went fine and the executable seems to work.

Commands like `ghc-mod --version` or `ghc-mod boot` work as expected.

Then, I installed haskell-mode on emacs and modified .emacs to use ghc. But when I tried to open a Haskell file, emacs froze saying "Initializing...".

What is the problem?

GHC version: 7.10.2
cabal version: 1.22.6.0 using version 1.22.4.0 of the cabal library
ghc-mod version: 5.3.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.10.2

**Edit 1: 16/8/2015 11:10**

Here are the lines I added to my `.emacs`:

```
; haskell-mode
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-indentation-mode)

; ghc-mod for haskell
; I added to list path to ghc elisp file because I read somewhere that that's
; better than installing it from MELPA. I DID try to install it from melpa
; though. Didn't solve anything.
(add-to-list `load-path "~/cabal/x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2/ghc-mod-5.3.0.0/elisp")

(autoload 'ghc-init "ghc" nil t)
(autoload 'ghc-debug "ghc" nil t)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (ghc-init)))
```

Emacs freeze when I try to open a haskell file for the first time. So I guess it stacks in an infinite loop inside `ghc-init()`.

**Edit 2: 16/8/2015 21:16**

Output from `ghc-debug` is [here](http://jpst.it/A-PW/)

Comment: Not enough info, I'd guess, but maybe it will ring a bell for someone familiar with `ghc*`. Otherwise, try providing a specific, step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, including all steps, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @Drew It may seem incomplete but I really don't have any more info to provide. I just installed `ghc-mod` and when I try to open a Haskell file it just freezes. I'll add to my post the lines I added to my `.emacs` when I wanted to add `ghc-mod`.

Comment: FYI that instance of `\`load-path` would conventionally use a regular `'` quote than a backquote. (It seems like a standard backquote, though, so functionally that's not actually a problem here.)

Comment: @phils Thanks for the tip. But yeah, that's not the problem here. load path works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on `ghc-mod` github repo and they solved the issue.

You can view the solution in [this](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/542) issue's comments.